# Change returned table name from stored procedure at the SQL side

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have written a single stored procedure that returns 2 tables:

```
select * 
from workers

select *
from orders
```

I call this stored procedure from my C# application and get a `DataSet` with two tables, and everything is working fine.

My question is how can I change the tables name **at the SQL Server side** so that in the C# side I will be able to access it via a name (instead of `Tables[0]`):

```
myDataSet.Tables["workers"]...
```

I tried to look for the answer in Google but couldn't find it. Maybe the search keywords was not sufficient.

Comment: You say you want to change the tables name on the SQL side? The question seems more related to C# and probably ADO.NET. DataSets are not part of the SQL Server system the way you are refering to them

Comment: You could use an enum in C# to achieve something very similar, and you'll benefit from intellisense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot really do anything from the server-side to influence those table names - those names only exist on the client-side, in your ADO.NET code.

What you **can** do is on the client-side - add table mappings - something like:

```
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(YourSqlCommandHere);
dap.TableMappings.Add("Table", "workers");
dap.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "orders");
```

This would "rename" the `Table` (first result set) to `workers` and `Table1` (second result set) to `orders` before you actually fill the data. So after the call to

```
dap.Fill(myDataSet);
```

you would then have `myDataSet.Tables["workers"]` and `myDataSet.Tables["orders"]` available for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

The [TDS Protocol documentation](http://www.freetds.org/tds.html) (Which is the protocol used to return results from SQL Server) does not mention a "resultset name". So the only way you will ever be able to access the result sets in ADO.net is by the number as mentioned in your example.